# VB Script to automate web login issue

Tags: vbscript

Please help as I am getting errors on Internet Explorer trying using the vbscript below the html codes. I have tried searching this forum with no luck.

I am having creating a logon script for the following website:

```
enter code here`<form action="website address" method="post" name="redirect_me">
 <input type="HIDDEN" name="language" value="EN">
  <input type="HIDDEN" name="LOGININPUT" value="">
  <input type="HIDDEN" name="PASSWORDINPUT" value="">
  <input type="HIDDEN" name="TITLE" value="">
  <input type="HIDDEN" name="PRELOGINDOCS" value="TRUE">
</form>
                      <tr><td colspan="2"><img src="/images/trans.gif" height="5" border="0"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td colspan="2"><img src="/images/greenline.gif" height="1" border="0"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td colspan="2"><img src="/images/trans.gif" width="5" height="30"></td></tr>
                  <!-- Login (End) -->
```

I tried using the following script but it's not working. I tried using the same script for yahoo mail and it worked. I am not sure what's the issue but I am guessing it's something to do with object ID. Your help is much appreciated.

```
On Error Resume Next

Const PAGE_LOADED = 4

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Call objIE.Navigate("website address")

objIE.Visible = True

Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(100) : Loop

objIE.Document.all.LOGININPUT.Value = "Username"

objIE.Document.all.PASSWORDINPUT.Value = "Password"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

msgbox "Error: " & err.Description

End If

Call objIE.Document.all.login_form.submit

Set objIE = Nothing''
```

Comment: What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: Hi Geobits, I am getting "Error: Object doesn't support this property or method". I am really not sure what's going on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your login form is not called `login_form`.

Comment: Sorry I should have posted the entire code:
<!-- Login (Start) -->
<!-- Error (Start) -->

<!-- Error (End) -->
                          <form name="login_form" method="post" action="/lcbosod-ear/SODLogon" onsubmit="return validate_login(this);document.login_form.submit()">
                            <input type="HIDDEN" name="language" value="EN">

Comment: and the form's name is login_form as per codes above. so please let me know what I am doing wrong here. thanks.